# Is there a way to round a Duration dtype in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

In Pandas, you can round a Timedelta like this...

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Timedelta("1h20min").round("1h")
```

Can something similar be done in Polars?

When I try rounding a duration column, the error tells me this only works for date/datetime dtypes.

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a = pl.DataFrame({"times": [timedelta(seconds=15), timedelta(seconds=30)]})
a.select(pl.col("times").dt.round("1m"))
```

> InvalidOperationError: `round` operation not supported for dtype `duration[ns]` (expected: date/datetime)

Comment: Does dt.truncate work?

Comment: you may be able to bit-shift you way into trouble

Comment: Unfortunately, dt.truncate method also expects date/datetime types. |
InvalidOperationError: `round` operation not supported for dtype `duration[μs]` (expected: date/datetime)

Comment: Based on the answers here, might be worth a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is incredibly stupid... but as a hack, you can simply add your duration to a fixed date, round the resulting date, and then subtract the fixed date to get a rounded duration back.

```py
base_date = pl.from_epoch(pl.lit(0))
a.with_columns(t=(pl.col("times") + base_date).dt.round("1m") - base_date)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ times        ┆ t            │
│ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ duration[μs] ┆ duration[μs] │
╞══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 15s          ┆ 0µs          │
│ 30s          ┆ 1m           │
└──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to manually round the duration. This isn't as simple as I was hoping for.

```py
a = pl.DataFrame({"times": [timedelta(seconds=15), timedelta(seconds=31)]})

# round to nearest 10 second
a.with_columns(
    ((pl.col("times").dt.seconds() / 10).round().cast(int) * 10).alias("nearest_10_sec")
)
# then cast the column as a duration if needed
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────┬────────────────┐
│ times        ┆ nearest_10_sec │
│ ---          ┆ ---            │
│ duration[μs] ┆ i64            │
╞══════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 15s          ┆ 20             │
│ 31s          ┆ 30             │
└──────────────┴────────────────┘
```